# Mocha tests not running in root directory

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have the following start script in node:

```
"test": "mocha **/*.test.js"
```

This tests all files in subdirectories, but not the files in the root, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you're missing the single quote for glob pattern.

Before

```
"test": "mocha **/*.test.js"
```

After

```
"test": "mocha '**/*.test.js'"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Have you tried using absolute paths? you could try `<root folder name>/**/*/.test.js`

Comment: The file may move around so I can't hard code the root.

Comment: then that would be hard to determine what files you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried... but I would try something like this:

```
"test": "mocha **/*.test.js & mocha ./*.js"
```

This is splitting the test sentence in 2 DOS commands...

```
mocha **/*.test.js <-- will run on the files inside the test dir
mocha ./*.js <-- will run on the files on the root...
```

Mocha looks for test script files INSIDE the test dir... so MAYBE you could try this:

```
"test": "mocha **/*.test.js & mocha ../*.js"
```

.

```
mocha ../*.js <-- look for js files inside the parent of the target directory
```